# Build into it meaning in the given context

Tags: meaning-in-context

You don't say the joke right away, you **build into it**, and then you say it.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct?

What does **build into it** mean here?

Comment: **Build into** means: *construct something as part of a whole; create something to be an integral part of something else*. I think the speaker has meant the _you_ person makes a story and then make the joke as part of that.

Comment: Normally in story telling we would say "build up to it" (where it=the punchline), not "build into it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the "it" refers to the joke so it's not as important as the first part: **build into**. As a native speaker who has lived in Ontario, Canada for his whole life, **build up to** sounds better to me. **Build into** works, but it sounds stiff.

### As for the meaning:

When someone **builds into** or **builds up to** a joke, it means that they are adding more content to the joke before telling the punchline. Normally, **building into** something is used in the form "build *something* into *something else*". In that context, it means to make the first thing inside of the second thing so that it's part of the second thing. In the context of an event like telling a joke, "build into" has a different meaning. When you **build into** a joke, it means that you are **building** a joke so that when you lead **into** the punchline, it'll be funny. It probably sounds stiff to me because **build into** has two meanings and the first meaning is much more common.
When you **build up to** a joke, you are **building up** the joke (or more pedantically, building the joke up), making it bigger (and funnier) until you tell the punchline. It works nicely this way - when something **builds up**, it gets bigger over time. For me, **build into** misses the idea that it could have been a weaker joke, but you were improving it by adding more.